# X is any point on AB and the median AD of triangle ABC meets XC at Y.Prove that XY/YC = AX/XB

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles

X is any point on AB and the median AD of triangle ABC meets XC at Y.Prove that **XY/YC = AX/XB**.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  What have you tried ? Will similarity of triangles help here ?

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Let $XE||AD$. Then $$\frac{XY}{YC}=\frac{ED}{DC}=\frac{ED}{DB}=\frac{AX}{AB}\not =\frac{AX}{XB}$$

Comment: How do you insert/make the image in latex? Can you please show me?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг, It's made using [GeoGebra](http://www.geogebra.org/), not $\LaTeX$.

Comment: All right, but then how would I insert an image of this  kind, or draw this  image in latex? I knew the answer to this question, but  was not able to insert the image.